# How to convert a string such as "5e+24" into an integer?

Tags: elixir

I have an external API which returns numbers as strings in the following format

```
5e+24
```

which is supposed to mean a number equal to `5 * 10^24` ==> 5 with 24 zeros.

Does Elixir have a capacity to convert such numbers into integers?

And what is this format even called?

Comment: You reverted my edits to your question that clarified that you are asking for an integer  based on your replies to zwippie: 
`5000000000000000000000000 == 5.0e24` can only be true for integers.  Please clarify what you mean by "decimal". As it stands the question is not specific enough.

Comment: Also if the question is not about erlang, you should not tag it so.

Comment: You've been given several good answers to your question.  If there are followup questions you should open new questions--not add additional questions via comments.  Or at the very least edit your original question to include the additions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is sometimes called *scientific notation* or *E notation*.

These numbers can be parsed from a string to a float in Elixir with `Float.parse`:

```
iex> Float.parse "3.1e+4" 
{31000.0, ""}
iex> Float.parse "5e+24" 
{5.0e24, ""}
```

As you can see in the last example, it returns the number in E notation but it's still a float you can work with.

Beware though of all the pitfalls a float type has. If, for example, you try to get a nice string representation of this number, [strange things can happen](https://floating-point-gui.de/):

```
{number, _} = Float.parse("5e+24")
Float.to_string number        
# "5.0e24"
:erlang.float_to_binary number
# "5.00000000000000045298e+24"
:erlang.float_to_binary number, decimals: 0 
"5000000000000000452984832"
```

Comment: The question is how to make it 5 with 24 zeros.

Comment: In the end, I  need that number as Integer. How would I convert `5.0e24` into one?

Comment: Your question was: what is this notation called and how do I parse it to a number.

Comment: `5000000000000000000000000 == 5.0e24` ==> false

Comment: Yes, I've tried those ways to convert it into an integer, as well  `trunc(..)`, `floor(..)`. However, none of them has converted the float into a proper integer which is `500000...(24 zeros)`

Answer (score 2):

You could split the string and multiply it yourself:

```elixir
[a, b] = String.split("5e+24", "e+")
String.to_integer(a) * 10 ** String.to_integer(b)
```

Comment: But that isn't a normal way to do it, it's a hack. What if one time  "5e24" got returned, without +?

Comment: You didn't ask that in your question. What if you got `5.678e2`? You need to ask a more precise question.

Comment: If that got returned, your solution wouldn't work either. You've proposed a hack, that is

Comment: It's not a hack, it's the answer to the question you asked. The problem is, it looks like you didn't ask for what you actually want. I've asked for clarification above.

Answer (score 1):

zwippie's answer deals with floats but, as he mentions, floats have some issues. If you want a purely integer solution, I do not find an existing way to parse a string in scientific notation into an Elixir integer. You have to parse the integer yourself, for instance with something like:

```
defmodule BigInteger do
  
  def parse(s) do
    {i, e} = Integer.parse(s)
    e = String.downcase(e)
    if not String.starts_with?(e, "e") do
      {:error, "No  \"e\""}
    else
      e = String.slice(e, 1..-1)
      cond do
        String.starts_with?(e, "+") ->
          {exp, rest} = Integer.parse(String.slice(e, 1..-1))
          if rest != "" do
            IO.inspect(rest)
            {:error, "Not integer after \"e+\""}
          else
            {:ok, i * Integer.pow(10, exp)}
          end
        True ->
          {exp, rest} = Integer.parse(String.slice(e, 0..-1))
          if rest != "" do
            {:error, "Not integer after \"e\""}
          else
            {:ok, i * Integer.pow(10, exp)}
          end
      end
    end
  end
end

IO.inspect(BigInteger.parse("3e+24"))
IO.inspect(BigInteger.parse("4e24"))
IO.inspect(BigInteger.parse("5E24"))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Number](https://hexdocs.pm/number/Number.html) package to do this.

It accepts strings and floats:

```
Number.Delimit.number_to_delimited("5e+24")
```

yields:

`"5,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000.00"`

If you don't want the commas:

```
Number.Delimit.number_to_delimited("5e+24", delimiter: "")
```

Yields:

`"5000000000000000000000000.00"`

If you want nothing after the decimal point:

```
Number.Delimit.number_to_delimited("5e+24", delimiter: "", precision: 0)
```

yields:

`"5000000000000000000000000"`